# Python - Can't get "string.isalnum():" to work properly

Tags: python

I cannot get the code below to work properly. It works if the user enters numbers for the name and it prints the theName.isdigit. But if the user enters both numbers and letters, it accepts this and moves onto a welcome message that follows. Looking at this, is there a reason you can find why theName.isalnum is not working here but the one above is?

```
theName = raw_input ("What is your name?? ")

while theName.isdigit ():
    if theName.isdigit ():
        print "What kind of real name has just numbers in it?? Try again..."
    elif theName.isalnum ():
        print "What kind of name has any numbers in it?? Please try again..."
    elif theName.isalpha ():
        print "Ok, great"
        break
    theName = raw_input ("What is your name?? ")
```

Comment: Your top test `while theName.isdigit()` will be `False` unless all of the characters are digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
theName = raw_input ("What is your name?? ")

while not theName.isalpha ():
    if theName.isdigit ():
        print "What kind of real name has just numbers in it?? Try again..."
    elif theName.isalnum ():
        print "What kind of name has any numbers in it?? Please try again..."
    theName = raw_input ("What is your name?? ")
print "Ok, great"
```

The while condition should tell you when to stop looping, that is, when  the input `isalpha`. Then, because the while loop stops when the input is correct, you can move the logic for what to do in that case below the loop.

Looping on `isdigit` is problematic because the string `abc123` doesn't meet that condition, so you break out of the loop even though the name doesn't meet your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others your code has a few problems.

First, if the `theName` contains anything other than digits, you will never enter the `while` loop, because `isdigit()` will return `False`.

Next, the order of your tests means that you will only reach the `isalpha()` test if the entered name contains something other than letters or digits.

However, it is also overly complex. Assuming your goal is to get the user to enter a name consisting only of letters (i.e. no spaces, digits, or special characters)

```
theName = "1" # preseed with invalid value
firstTime = True
while not theName.isalpha():
    if not firstTime:
        print "Your name should not contain anything other than letters"
    theName = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
    firstTime = False

print "OK, great. Hi " + theName
```

This will repeatedly prompt until the user enters a valid name.

Comment: Ok great thank you. Is writing: 

'if not firstTime:' 

the same as writing: 

'if not theName.isalpha():' ??

Comment: Thank you for your help! Ive moved things around but still have a little prob. Code:

`while theName.isdigit ():
    if theName.isdigit ():
        print ("What kind of real name has numbers in it??? Try again...")
    elif theName.isalpha():
        print ("Ok, great.")
        break
    theName = input ("What is your name?? ")

while theName.isalnum():
    if theName.isalnum():
        print ("No real name has both letters and numbers in it??? Try again...")
    elif theName.isaplha():
        print ("Ok, great.")
        break
    theName = input ("What is your name? ")`

Comment: Sorry i am not sure how to lay this out properly?

Comment: That code produced this: 

What is your name?  4353
What kind of real name has numbers in it??? Try again...
What is your name??  63463
What kind of real name has numbers in it??? Try again...
What is your name??  gdsg4253
No real name has both letters and numbers in it??? Try again...
What is your name?  5345gsrg
No real name has both letters and numbers in it??? Try again...
What is your name?  gdrsfhre
No real name has both letters and numbers in it??? Try again...
What is your name?    

This is not working though as when someone does add letters, it still doesnt accept?

Comment: Ok i changed it to this and it works perfectly. Thank you to both of you guys. Sorry for the mess in trying to reply as well, but i do appreciate your help!

`while not theName.isalpha ():
    if not theName.isalpha ():
        print ("Please only use letters for your name\n")
        theName = input ("What is your name? ")
    if theName.isalpha ():
        print ("Ok, great!")
        break`

If someone could explain how i can get my text to display properly though for next time? that would be awesome!